# File upload Java without html form

Tags: java, file, upload

I'm currently working on a desktop application written in Java in which a user will upload files to a certain location. I'm sort of a beginner in Java and I was wondering how can I make the file upload part. I looked for solutions on the Internet but all of them seem to use html forms and Java servlets. I would like, if possible, to make the file upload without html code as my application will not run on a browser, it will be a desktop application. An example of a file upload written in Java (without html) would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean using awt swings?

Comment: Yes. There will be a file chooser to select the file.

Comment: Then y asking here? You have got what you want to do. So do it or google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) to let users select the files and then use an FTP client, such as Apache's [`FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) to upload items on some FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

If its a swing application, use file chooser to select the file and transfer it to the server through sockets. Connect to the server, open output stream and transfer the file data. That's it.

Comment: So, basically, I also need to build a server to handle uploads

Comment: Nope, if you already have a servlet, then just connect to the servlet from the Java client, open output stream and transfer the file data.

Comment: then where you have planned to upload it?